# 'fopen' returns malformed 'fp'

Tags: c++, linux

### Environment

- Ubuntu 16.x (x64)
- C++

### Use-case

```
    FILE* fp = 0;
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != stat(pFullPath, &st)) {
        if (0 == (fp = fopen(pFullPath, "w+b")))// Create The File
            return HRESULT_GET_ERRNO();
        _ASSERT(0 != fileno(fp));
```

### Problem description

fopen always succeeds returning a valid pointer
sporadically ‘fileno’ returns ZERO and `m_pf->_fileno == 0`

**What might cause the malformed ‘`fp`’ ?**

### 'm_fp' dump

```
_flags  -72539008   int
_IO_read_ptr    0x0 char *
_IO_read_end    0x0 char *
_IO_read_base   0x0 char *
_IO_write_base  0x0 char *
_IO_write_ptr   0x0 char *
_IO_write_end   0x0 char *
_IO_buf_base    0x0 char *
_IO_buf_end     0x0 char *
_IO_save_base   0x0 char *
_IO_backup_base 0x0 char *
_IO_save_end    0x0 char *
_markers        0x0 _IO_marker *
_chain          0x7fe6368cf540 <_IO_2_1_stderr_>    _IO_FILE *
_fileno         0   int
_flags2         0   int
_old_offset     94543438232832  __off_t
_cur_column     0   unsigned short
_vtable_offset  7 '\a'  signed char
_shortbuf       char [1]
_lock           x55fc9c068e50   _IO_lock_t *
_offset         -1  __off64_t
__pad1          0x55fc9c070210  void *
__pad2          0x55fc9c068e60  void *
__pad3          0x0 void *
__pad4          0x7fe644d41a93  void *
__pad5          0   size_t
_mode           0   int
_unused2        char [20]
```

Comment: Need to see the [mcve] you use to reproduce this.

Comment: What's the value of 'pFullPath'? does it refer to a (existing or not-existing) file in an existing directory?

Comment: I don't know how to have that reproduced, that is the whole point, it happens sporadically, it I would know how to have that reproduced I would have not needed stackoverflow assistance

Comment: @NadavRub we can't debug the program (especially since we don't have it). Figuring out how to reproduce it reliably might well lead you to a solution. This site is not for asking vague questions about vague problems and hoping that someone will give you the one correct solution from a sea of possible causes. You're supposed to do the legwork yourself, ask a question here when you have reduce the problem to something meaningful.

Comment: At most cases problems happen in complex and big code bases, and, are hard to isolate, all that I wanna know is if any1 has experienced something similar... no need to compile the code and run, Any1 encountered similar problems? cool, his feedback can help

Comment: 'pFullPath' doesn't exist, if it would, and, in such a way causing 'fopen' to fail I would expect it to return zero... shouldn't it? maybe I am missing something here...

Comment: The correct test for this is `_ASSERT(fileno(fp) != -1)`, It's an error to assume that `0` is [not a valid file descriptor number](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fileno.html).

Comment: @Petesh why -1? I propose -42. Looks prettier.

Comment: use fopen_s(...)

Comment: @NadavRub It'd be slightly better to test return value of `fopen` against `NULL`, so it would be more explicit it is actually returning a pointer.

Comment: Btw, just why are you testing the file descriptor value against 0? It does not mean error or failure or anything, it is actually guaranteed to be a valid file descriptor, since it is coming directly out of `fopen` call (assuming no memory corruption etc). It can't be invalid. It's of course curious to have values 0, 1 or 2 (stdin, stdout, stderr), but it is not an error (at least not in this piece of code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing descriptor 0 before calling `fopen` can (and will) cause 0 to be re-used. This mechanism is commonly used to set child process standard input before exec.

Having standard input be closed before program starts (via exec) will also cause first opened file to get descriptor 0.

Undefined behavior in the program can cause anything, randomly...

Also, perhaps your code doesn't behave like you expect. Add debug prints in addition to asserts. Check if it asserts wih invslid file. Etc.

Anything more, can't be said with the info you provide.

Comment: "Closing descriptor 0 before calling fopen can (and will) cause 0 to be re-used." - this might happen indirectly by underlying 3rd party components used

Thank you, this has helped !!!